# How to write a bash loop to create index.php in all images directories

Tags: for-loop

I'm on a mission to prevent Index Of /images across about 300 websites...

My question is how can I make a for loop to use the shell command 'touch' to create index.php in all /image directories recursively?  The depth can go 5 directories deep or deeper, I really don't know how deep it can go...I hope someone can help me with this as google hasn't (most likely my fault searching the wrong keywords...)

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy, try this bash script:

```
visit_dirs() 
{    
    # create the needed file
    touch index.php

    # if you don't need them, you can undo the action, etc.
    #rm index.php

    # just for informational purposes
    pwd
    ls index.php

    # the most important thing: recursion, so that this script will work with 
    # directories structures of any depth

    # first, the loop over all files (warning: this will probably break if files or
    # directories contain spaces in their name)
    for d in *; do

        # if d is directory...
        if [ -d $d ]
        then
            # visit it
            (cd $d; visit_dirs)
        fi

    done
}

# call the function        
visit_dirs
```

Comment: Is there a way to add in "if index.php or index.* already exists, skip that directory" because I would hate for there to be an index.html already in a directory and it creates an index.php which overrides the index.html causing a blank page where content used to be...

Comment: Yes, checking for file existance in bash is easy:

    if [ -e index.* ] ; then echo "index exists"; fi

So you should just add appropriate check before comment # visit it

Comment: You might need to use this though: checking if file doesn't exist is:  if [ ! -e index.* ]